# Is Developing an Instagram Reels Web Downloader and Anonymous Story Viewer Considered Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam

"Are building Tools Such as an Instagram Reels Web Downloader and Anonymous Story Viewer Ethically Acceptable According to Islamic Principles? What Might be the Implications for User Privacy and Platform Engagement? Consider that the stories are public, potentially reducing privacy concerns, and the web downloader leaves the choice of content selection to the user."